# Creating routing for a static site using Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, static

I am creating a static site, (HTML, CSS, JS) using nodeJS and express for the server...

I am trying to create routes, so that the user sees `/about`, as opposed to about.html...
For the main, home page (home.html), it works fine. However, when trying to access the pages using the defined routes via `app.get`, I keep getting errors - any pointers...

Code is as follows  - my styling and JS files ate in the `public` directory and the HTML files are in the `views` directory :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/views')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/home.html');
});

app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/about.html');
});

app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/contact.html');
});

// app.use(express.static('public'));
// app.use(express.static('views'));
// console.log(__dirname);
module.exports = app;
```

The error I get is :

```
Cannot GET /views/contact.html
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? You have to provide the details

Comment: Have updated the post with the error @AHMEDSAJJAD

Answer (score 2):

if your foldering is like the following photo you can do like this:
[image]

```
app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/about.html');
});

app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/contact.html');
});
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/home.html');
});
```

Comment: Your code is the same as mine, just you have used arrow functions instead...It produces the same result?! Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: It’s not same, ‘/‘ route should be the last route in the file

Comment: Still getting the same issue, unfortunately... `Cannot GET /views/contact.html`

Comment: Yes, my folder structure is exactly that, which is why it is more confusing. Here is mine

node_modules
public
    css
    img 
    js
views
    about.html
    contact.html
    home.html
 app.js
 server.js
 config.env
 package.json
 package-lock.json

Comment: ```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config({ path: './config.env' });
const app = require('./app');

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}...`);
});
```

Comment: I don’t have a idea, you can send me github link, I’ll check it